Chow moving lemma with additional property
All varieties are over algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface. Let $D$ be an irreducible divisor on $S$, $H$ be another divisor and $Z\subset S$ be a closed subset.
Assume I know that $D\cap H=\varnothing$. Does exist $D'$ rationally equivalent to $D$, such that $D'$ intersects $Z$ properly and $D'\cap H=\varnothing$?
If possible the proof should be elementary and use something like Bertini theorem.
If $H$ is an exceptional divisor of some blow-up than this statement follows from the classical Chow moving lemma.
In the case when $S$ is fibered over some curve and $D,H$ are two fibers, the statement holds as well.
But I don't know what to do in general case.

That is not true.  The divisor $D$ could be rigid.  Also, even when $S$ is fibered over a curve, fibers need not be rationally equivalent (it depends on whether or not the target of the morphism is a rational curve).

Can you explain what is a counterexample? Or where can I read about it?

Let $S$ be the blowing up of the projective plane at one point.  Let $D$ be the exceptional divisor.  Let $H$ be the inverse image of a line that does not contain the point.  Let $Z$ be $D$.

But if I know that $H$ is contracted (there is a map $\pi$ from $S$ to may be singular $S'$, such that $\pi^{-1}(p)=H$ and $\pi$ induces an isomorphism $S\backslash H\to S'\backslash p$) than this statement is true, yes?
